# Htaccess Redirect makes server to load images and other resources twice

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to improve the speed of a website. Used WebPageTest.org to get the waterfall and see what could be causing issues etc.

I come across that due to htacess non-www to www domain redirect images, are being requested twice, one for non-www and then another for a domain with www prefix. (See image)

> [image: Waterfall Requests image]

I thought I might ask here see if anyone has come across this issue and how did you solve it? I did a bit of research but couldn't really find anything useful.

Maybe someone can point me to the right direction?

Btw this is my htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a condition that excludes assets:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond $1 !\.(png|jpe?g|gif|js|css)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```